# UncaughtExceptionHandler prob

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a class (in it's own file)

```
public class UncaughtExceptionHandler implements 

 java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
```

In my main program I have the following:-

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( new UncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

When compiling I get the following error:-

```
cannot instantiate the type Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
```

Am I missing some basic point here?

Here is the code:
    import java.io.*;

import android.content.*;

public class UncaughtExceptionHandler implements 
        java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    private final Context myContext;

```
public UncaughtExceptionHandler(Context context) {
    myContext = context;
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        boolean crashedOnLastClose = false;
    MyApplication.writeProgressLog("before isfinishing".ERROR_FILE_NAME);
    // The application is being destroyed by the O/S
        crashedOnLastClose = true;

        MyApplication.writeProgressLog("after isfinishing",ERROR_FILE_NAME);


    }   


}
```

Comment: are you implementing all methods of the interface?

Comment: you have to override method [uncaughtException(Thread,Throwable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html#uncaughtException%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable%29)

Comment: You get an error when **compiling** or when **running** your program? It seems to me very strange to get the "can't instantiate type" error at compile time...

Comment: It looks like you are calling the 'Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler' in a static context according to what you have posted above. It's an instance method, not a static method. Can you post your code?

Comment: this is the code for the handler

Answer (score 2):

**ISSUE**

In the statement

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

---

```
new UncaughtExceptionHandler()
```

is actually

```
new java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
```

This is *throwing the exception*

**SOLUTION**

Check file `UncaughtExceptionHandler.java`

Find the package: (*on the top of the file*)

```
package your.package;
```

Now go to your main program

Replace

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

with

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new your.package.UncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion and that still gives the cannot instantiate message

Comment: use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new your.package.UncaughtExceptionHandler(this))` ... If this didn't work, try to change the name of your class to a different name

Comment: After all this I saw that this wasnt the first line after super.onCreate and so moved it up and all is ok.   My thanks to all who have helped, only I could see the positioning so I am sorry to have wasted time. As a relative newcomer to Android I am interested to know the principle behind it having to be the first line.

Answer (score 0):

UncaughtExceptionHandler is an interface, you cannot instantiate an interface. You need to implement its methods.

Your code should look like this:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        // your code
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have just entered the implementation code exactly as your example in the main class and it errors with 'must override a superclass method'   I seem to be getting mixed up about using StackOverflow.  In order to show code after a request tod that where do I go to respond with a code block?  Is it edit the original?  Also this comment area doesnt seem to allow for pressing ener to start a new lin.

Comment: try removing the @Override annotation

Answer (score 0):

My IDE is having a similar problem with the same construct using @Override.
The method uncaughtException(Thread, Throwable) of type new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){} must override a superclass method:

```
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler uce = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                String s = "ssh to user@" + host + " failed";
                log.error(s);
                throw new IllegalStateException(s, e);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Turns out I had Java Compiler Compliance Level set to 1.5. Changing it to 1.6 fixes this problem (Eclipse Indigo).  (WHY???)